# Javascript: load with Ajax a javascript and transmit data to it as to a php script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am loading my script like this:

```
    var myTestString = "/modules/admin";
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "../../includes/test_tooltip.js",
       data: "module="+myTestString,
       dataType: "script"
     });
```

Is it possible to have access to module variable in my test_tooltip.js like this?

```
console.log("I am loaded!" + module);
```

My scenario is like this. I sometimes need to load that javascript and when i do, i do it in different modules, and i need this javascript to know which module because he will have to do some requests based on the module.

In php i know you can acces data with $_REQUEST["module"], if it could be done in javascript similar would be great.

Comment: what's should respond your test_tooltip.js when you launch your query ?

Comment: Does this actually have anything to do with PHP?

Comment: @Awea : test_tooltip.js will have to put some tooltips on some elements, and the text of that tooltips depends on what parameters i send to it.

Comment: @Ash : It doesn't involve PHP directly, i just need to send some data with that ajax request to the js file, as we do with PHP when making a request. I wished that your code below worked but it doesn't unfortunately.

Comment: I use `window.variable` and `delete window.variable` and case closed. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myTestString = "/modules/admin";
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "../../includes/test_tooltip.js",
   context: { module: myTestString },
   dataType: "script"
 });
```

Your returned javascript should be executed within scope of the context object given to #.ajax, so you could then do:

```
console.log("I am loaded!" + this.module);
```

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately. Any more ideas? have you tested it works for you? maybe i am doing something wrong. It says data not defined.

Comment: Okay I've modified the answer with an alternative solution